# Should I use xSemaphoreGiveFromISR() or xSemaphoreGive() in STM32 HAL interrupt callbacks?

Tags: freertos, isr, stm32-hal

I've implemented a fault task in the FreeRTOS which is taking a binary semaphore used as a fault flag. That fault flag is triggered by the STM32 HAL error callback functions, such as `HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback` or `HAL_UART_ErrorCallback`. If an error occurs, error callbacks functions will call `signalFault()` function, which will raise the fault flag by giving the binary semaphore.

My question is: is my `signalFault()` function treated as an interrupt service routine (ISR) or not, because it is being called in the HAL ISR error callbacks? Do I need to call `xSemaphoreGiveFromISR()` or `xSemaphoreGive()` function in `signalFault()` function to raise the fault flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you should use `xSemaphoreGiveFromISR` if the calling context is an ISR.
A function called from an ISR is still part of the ISR.

Comment: Do you have a reference to your statement?

Comment: Definately the FromISR version. Clearly stated in the user manual that only FromISR functions can be called from an ISR.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  Do you have a reference to your statement that "A function called from an ISR is still part of the ISR."?

Comment: @IvanVnucec Why should just calling a function change anything to the calling context ? Same applies to code executed by a function call from a task, which is still part of the task context, right ?

Comment: @IvanVnucec the reference is knowledge. If you call a function from the interrupt handler you are still in the handler. Only return from the handler changes the context.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not trust us then simple check if you are in the interrupt. It will be 100% safe.

```
int isInISR( void ) 
{
    return ( portNVIC_INT_CTRL_REG & portVECTACTIVE_MASK );
}
```

and in your code:

```
if(isInISR()) xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(...);
else xSemaphoreGive(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've looked up what is portNVIC_INT_CTRL_REG register and VECTACTIVE bit here https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/arm-cortex-m-exceptions-and-nvic#icsr-register and indeed with your solution I can be certain that I'm in ISR. Once I check my code, I will approve your answer.

Comment: For the interested: I've stumbled on the xPortIsInsideInterrupt() defined inside portmacro.h header file under FreeRTOS directory. Function returns if we are inside interrupt by checking Interrupt Program Status Register (IPSR).